# Problema con el background en 2 columnas , css grid

Tags: css, scss, grid, css-grid-layout

quiero crear dos columnas a full width como ven en la imagen con css grid. He logrado hacerlo, el detalle es que coloco un width a la caja del hijo y trato de alinearla al centro y se me hecha a perder.

Pueden ver el código aquí. https://codepen.io/jhoedram/pen/wmmaeR

```css
.columnas {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(2,1fr);
  min-height: 350px;
}

.columna1 {
  background-color: orange;
  justify-self:end;
}

.columna2 {
  background-color: skyblue;
}

.content-columm {
  width: 350px;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;;
}
```

```html
<div class="columnas">
  <div class="columna1">
    <div class="content-columm">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque aliquam tempora minus sunt dolor asperiores eveniet, repellendus ad cupiditate molestias assumenda hic tenetur illum quidem sapiente vero. Tempore, quae illum.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="columna2">
    <div class="content-columm">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum, ipsa! Explicabo ullam voluptatem, esse tempore, officiis ratione velit laborum soluta deleniti dignissimos eum sapiente id quis modi eaque aspernatur eligendi.s
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

(ejecútenlo a pantalla completa para que vean el problema)

¿Qué puedo estar haciendo mal? Alguien me puede explicar.
Desde ya, muchas gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `justify-self:center;` hace lo que se espera, ajusta la celda al contenido y la centra. Si quieres que el *div* `.content-columm` esté centrado manteniendo el tamaño de `columna1` deberías ponerle un `margin:0 auto` al contenido y no  usar `justify-self`

Answer (score 0):

Espero haber entendido tu problemática...

Modifica tu clase:

**De**

```
.content-columm {
  width: 350px;
}
```

**a**

```
 .content-columm {
      width: auto;
    }
```

Comment: No, :( 
Con eso logro que el background se respete solamente. Quiero eso, pero el contenedor debe tener un width de diferentes dimensiones, de todos modos, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar los siguientes estilos:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.columnas {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    min-height: 350px;
}

.columna1 {
    background-color: orange;
}

.columna2 {
    background-color: skyblue;
}

.content-columm {
    background: grey; /* para ver espacio ocupado por el contenido */

    margin: 10% 0 0 10%;
    width: 80%;
}
```

La alineación al centro del contenido de las cajas puedes lograrlo empleando *margins* en la clase `.content-columm`. Con un *width* en esta controlas el espacio que quieres que ocupe el contenido. Usa porcentajes en los márgenes y ancho que indiques para mantener el responsive.

*PD: He movido tus estilos para **body** al principio usando un selector universal para que hagan de reset a todos los elementos.*

Comment: Mi idea era dejar a un lado los paddings o margins, se supone que estoy usando css grid y quería lograrlo con sus mismas propiedades. La alineación quería lograrlo a través de justify-self: center, pero veo que al aplicarlo me causa un efecto raro.

Comment: No se se está reñido usar márgenes con *grid* para conseguir lo que deseas, generalmente se usan combinaciones de diferentes técnicas. Saludos.

Comment: Si, lo sé. El Mi tema más que todo es por curiosidad, me gustaría saber por qué pasa esto.

Answer (score 0):

el tema es que no por que el item padre es grid los hijos lo seran, por lo que el problema es ese, los hijo que lo nesesiten tambien deben ser grid y todas los css nesesario para el, te dejo el resultado

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;;
}

.columnas {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(2,1fr);
}

.columna1 {
  display: grid;
  background-color: #DC5437;
  color:white;
  text-align: center;
  justify-items: center;
}

.columna2 {
  background-color: skyblue;
  
}

.columna1 .content-columm{
      width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="columnas">
  <div class="columna1">
    <div class="content-columm"><h1>Allan loves Groove. Here’s why…</h1>
      <h3>We’ve tried everything, from Gmail on up to the enterprise level products. Nothing felt right until we found Groove.</h3> 
      <p>Allan Branch of Less Accounting</p>
      <a href="#">More customer stories</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="columna2">
    <div class="content-columm">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum, ipsa! Explicabo ullam voluptatem, esse tempore, officiis ratione velit laborum soluta deleniti dignissimos eum sapiente id quis modi eaque aspernatur eligendi.s
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```